# Xamarin Android Amazon Web Services

Tags: c#, android, amazon-web-services, xamarin

Can someone please provide me with an example of how to upload images from Xamarin Android to Amazon Webservices. I for the life of me followed every example and NONE work. I have all the details, bucketname, file to upload, secret key, but nothing works

Comment: Can you update your question with the code that you are trying to use and actual issue (exception and/or http response error from AWS) that you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a full working project demonstrating the AWS Xamarin SDK and S3 here https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/tree/master/XamarinSamples/S3